# Out of memory, possible flushing

Tags: php

I have a local script to do conversion data from one webapp to another one, reading from exported xml and write to local mysql database.

after convert done, then I upload database online.

To optimize debug, my import.php use include to split sections:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/1/index.php");

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/2/index.php");

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/3/index.php");

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/4/index.php");

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/5/index.php");

....

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/20/index.php");
```

Cause of the big data to convert I get into `Fatal error: Out of memory` after some time....for example on 5/index.php.

Ok I can increase memory_limit, but is it possible to free/flush memory after each section (include_once) to prevent this? How?

Comment: Is it php-cli ?

Comment: @Cid no, it isn't